# Firefox extension request is interpreted as CORS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

When porting my Chrome extension to a Firefox web-extension, I can't make any network requests because they are blocked by the same origin policy.

As an example:

```
const headers = {"content-type": "application/json" };
window.fetch(myDomain + "/api/v3/token", { method: "GET", headers: headers });
```

This fails with the following error:

[image]

Is there a way to configure the Firefox extension to not consider these requests CORS? The same code works just fine as a Google Chrome extension.

This holds true even if the request goes to localhost.

I have tried this with jquery's `$.ajax` method and axios library to get the same result (works in Chrome, doesn't work in Firefox) so I don't think the problem is limited to the `window.fetch` API.

EDIT: I know that I can add a CORS handler on the server side, but I'm trying not to do that. And why does this work in Chrome and not in Firefox?

EDIT 2: The extension is a popup

Comment: WebExtensions API in Firefox still has many bugs even in the core parts so maybe this is yet another one.

Comment: Does it work when you do the same in the Firefox Scratchpad (Shift+F4 in Firefox)?

Answer (score 8):

This is documented here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Host_permissions

In short you need to add a host permission for localhost to mame same-origin requests by default.  I don't know why Google Chrome handles this differently.

Comment: Add what to where how?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who come across this issue in 2022:

Chrome is deprecating manifest V2 in favor of v3. So you'll probably end up using

```
host_permissions: ["*://domain/*"]
```

Firefox does not support manifest v3 yet (as of april 2022), you need to use:

```
permissions: ["*://domain/*"]
```

**HOWEVER**

If, like me, you were (successfully) specifying the port while working with chrome (i.e `http://localhost:4000/*`), it will not work with firefox. You need to use `http://localhost/*` instead, **which works with both chrome and firefox.**

Comment: To clarify your answer: one needs to use the *match pattern* `http://localhost/*` (without the port) and be given access to any port, as per docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#sect2 Right now, your answer reads ambiguously (as if you are limited to standard port in Firefox)

Comment: Yes thank you for specifying this.
I had read the documentation up to this part: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#host_permissions But did not looked into the details of match patterns since it worked on chrome.
It's worth specifying that the user interface on `about:addons` list the permission as valid and no warning is raised when using the port, but it is then silently ignored

Comment: I fn love you <3

Answer (score 2):

Some notes for Firefox extensions using `"manifest_version": 3`:

Firefox is performing a [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) for these network requests. Chrome doesn't.

This may lead to unexpected behavior, given that this preflights are `HTTP OPTIONS` requests.

One may have to add the `OPTIONS` methods on the server endpoint.

One may also have to setup origin and header on the server endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

My Firefox extension is using a V3 manifest and I was facing the exact CORS issue regardless of having `host_permissions` property configured in the manifest.

And as [@Baccata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5627467/baccata) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73388604/4788639), it seems like Firefox is performing a CORS preflight request while Chrome doesn't.

I managed to resolve the issue by adding some basic CORS handling to my Go backend.

```golang
cors := cors.New(cors.Options{
  AllowedMethods: []string{http.MethodOptions, http.MethodHead, http.MethodGet, http.MethodPut, http.MethodDelete},
  AllowedHeaders: []string{"*"},
})

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, cors.Handler(router)))
```